# How to checkout a specific commit inside magit?

Tags: magit

Inside the `magit` log history, I can see the list of commits. How do I roll back to a specific commit from the list?

I can move to that commit and use `d` to see the diff/change of that commit, but I do not know how to check it out.

Comment: You probably want to read about the `git reset` command (and especially the difference between a hard and a soft reset). Magit binds `x` to a soft reset, and `C-u x` to a hard reset.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I like to do this with <kbd>bb</kbd>. You'll be prompted for a branch with completion, and the current element (e.g. navigate to it with <kbd>ll</kbd>) will be the default.  Then simply press <kbd>RET</kbd> to check out that commit.  It's also possible to paste a commit hash during the <kbd>bb</kbd> input.

Comment: Bearing in mind that while the title says "checkout", the question text actually says "rollback".

Comment: That's useful to tag previous commits too, which goes to HEAD.